# What is the best way to accept ether payment without using a third party payment service?

Tags: ether, payments, documentation

I am new in Ethereum blockchain technology. I wanted to make a payment gateway for accepting Ethereum.

I ran ethereum rinkeby testnet on my local machine and tested Ether transfer to another wallet. I wanted to know what is the best way to accept ether payment without using a third party payment service.

Can anyone help me by giving good resources and best practice for accepting Ethereum payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search couple hour I found some idea for accepting ether payment.
First of all I need to create new account/address for every payment request where user can send ether and then poll the account balances until the desired amount is received. Once amount is received then it send to master account.